# Is there a way for an entry widget to automatically be selected

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a popup window with an entry widget using Tk, is there a way for the cursor to already be flashing when it pops up, so that the user doesn't have to click the entry widget to enter text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .focus()

```
widget_name.focus()
```